Finding spikes for my wide foot with Morton's toe
My foot length is 25.5cm I ordered a Nike rival S shoe with same size for sprinting but unfortunately it did not fit. Although My feet was even loose on the tip but it was so tight from the sides and the shoe tongue was pressed out. What kind of shoe should I order?



Try New Balance spiked running shoes.  Nike shoes tend to run narrow.  The standard width for New Balance shoes is a D width, which is wider than most brands.  For some shoe models, New Balance also offers a 2E width.
You don't specify the width of your foot, but it doesn't look too wide, and doesn't seem to have any large protrusions.  Given the lacing of your existing shoes, it appears that you do have an atypically high instep.  But I'm not a medical professional.
If you can, get yourself into a quality running or triathlon store.  You feet, knees, and back with thank you.  If you can't do that, give New Balance spiked running shoes a try.
